# How to handle downloading file progress by DropNet

Tags: rest-client, dropnet

I'm using DropNet to download file from Dropbox, I see it use the RestClient for execute the reques.

My question:
Is there anyway to get progress status during the Download?
I mean, if I'm downloading a few Megabyte file size, how I'll know that the download is in progress?!

Shouldn't we have for example callback for inform the caller about status?, each package call this call bace with status like package number?, so client can wait or retry...?

Thanks
Joseph

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the answer to this is no. RestSharp doesn't support this so DropNet doesn't either.

You could proabably take a look at DropNetRT which is based off HttpClient https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNetRT. It doesn't currently support progress out of the box but could be modified using something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8492195/75946

If you do have a go at this let me know so I can either help you out or include your changes into the project. I've had a bit of feedback for this feature but haven't found a good way to do it yet.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look and will update when have such an updates. Thanks